# Trying to edit records with sql queries but only allows me to edit one record

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I am trying to edit records with sql queries but it only lets me edit one record. I try to update projectname and projectnr. When I try to update both records none of them gets updated.Whenever I try to update projectname it allows me to change it. Projectnr won't update when I try that one alone.

```
            include("dbconfig.php");
            // $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            // mysql_select_db('projectsync');

            if( isset($_GET['edit']))
            {
                $id = $_GET['edit'];

                /*$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE projectnr='$id'");

                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $projectnr= $rows['projectnr'];
                    $projectnaam= $rows['projectnaam'];
                } */

                $query = "SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE projectnr='$id'";
                $projecten = $conn->prepare($query);

                try {
                    $projecten->execute(array());
                    $projecten->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach($projecten as $project){
                        $projectnr = $project['projectnr'];
                        // $email = $consultant['email'];
                        // $admin = $consultant['admin'];
                        $projectnaam = $project['projectnaam'];
                    }
                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "<script>$('Er iets is misgegaan, wilt u opnieuw proberen alstublieft!');</script>";
                }

                //$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                //$res = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klantnr='$id'");
                //$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }

            if( isset($_POST['newProject']))
            {
                $newProject = $_POST['newProject'];
                $id    = $_POST['projectnr'];

                /*$sql = "UPDATE klant SET naam='$newUsername', admin= '$newAdmin', password= '$newPass', username= '$newName' 
                WHERE klantnr='$id'";

                $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);
                $res   = mysql_query($sql)
                                            or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
                */

                try {
                    $query = "UPDATE projecten SET projectnaam='$newProject' WHERE projectnr='$id'";
                    $data = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $data->execute();
                    $row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            if(isset($_GET['delete']))
            {
                $id = $_GET['delete'];
                //$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klantnr='$id'");
                //$row= mysql_fetch_array($res);

                $res = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klantnr='$id'");
                $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                try {
                    include("dbconfig.php");

                    $sql = "DELETE FROM klant WHERE klantnr='$id'";

                    $conn->exec($sql);
                    echo "<script>alert('User successfully deleted.');</script>";
                    header("refresh: 0.4; url=manage.php");
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="nl">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
                    content="text/html";
                    charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Beheer gebruikers</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <header>
                    <center>
                        <img src="images/project-sync.png" /><br />
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="declaraties.php">Mijn Declaraties</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="projectkosten.php">Declareren</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="overzicht-projecten.php">Projecten</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="overzicht-users.php">Declaraties</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="manage.php">Manage Users</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </center>
                </header>
                <div class="main">
                    <center>
                        <div class="loginRegisterBox">
                            <form action="editp.php" method="POST" name="loginform" class="form-4" style="width: 300px">
                                <p>Projectnr: <input type="text" name="projectnr" value="<?php echo $projectnr; ?>"></p>
                                <p>Projectnaam <input type="text" name="newProject" value="<?php echo $projectnaam; ?>"></p>

                                <p><input type="submit" name="submitProject" value=" Update "/></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your if statement is wrong - you're updating `projectnr` if `$_GET['edit']` is set. I assume you want `$_POST['projectnr']`, to be consistent with the other fields

Comment: That said, there are much easier ways of doing this. For one, this is open to SQL injection. You're using PDO, so there's no reason not to use prepared statements. For another - instead of creating multiple queries if both fields are set, you're better off generating a single UPDATE based on what you need to change. As it stands, if you're editing both fields, then you're making four separate queries, and you only need to do two.

Comment: @andrewsi I use $_GET['edit'] to retrieve the projectnr from another page. "<td><a href='edit.php?edit=$row[projectnr]'>edit</td>"

Comment: OK. But the form at the bottom of the page uses POST, and also has no input called `edit`. So your first `if` statement is never going to get triggered.

Comment: @andresi But the if statement works, because if I `echo $id` it gives me the right `projectnr;`

Comment: It can't work the second time through. There is no `edit` input in that form.